# Emulator Install Log?

Tags: android

I am trying to port an application to pre 3.0 versions. I did some tweaking to the code using the Android support library and the code does compile. The problem is, when I launch the emulator and Eclipse tries to install my app, something goes wrong and the install process fails. However, there is no trace of any logs and nothing shows up in my logcat either (it is completely empty) that would provide me with more info as to just what exactly went wrong so I am a bit lost as to what to do....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the app is having trouble launching you should see some log messages in the Eclipse console view.  If the app never makes it to the emulator you won't see anything in logcat.